# Notification not displaying in Oreo but displaying in android 10

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have a simple chat app where the `notification` should pop up every time a new message arrives. I am using my physical device Moto G5 plus (Which is running Oreo) and the emulator pixel (Which is running the latest `android 10`). When I send a message from my moto to the emulator the notification pops up fine and works good but when I try the same from my `emulator` to `Moto` then my Moto only vibrates but doesn't show or pop any notification. Below are my codes. In `FirebaseMessaging` class I have implemented two methods one for oreo and above devices and one for below oreo devices to receive `notifications`.

My app is based on `Firebase` and `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

**FirebaseMessaging.java**

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private String channelId = "com.pappu5.navigation";

    private static final String id = "admin_channel";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentUser = sp.getString("Current_User", "None");


        String nType = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");


        if (nType.equals("PostNotification")) {

            String sender = remoteMessage.getData().get("sender");
            String pId = remoteMessage.getData().get("pId");
            String pTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("pTitle");
            String pDesc = remoteMessage.getData().get("pDesc");


            if (!sender.equals(currentUser)) {

                showPostNotification("" + pId, "" + pTitle, "" + pDesc);

            }
        } else if (nType.equals("ChatNotification")) {

            String sent = remoteMessage.getData().get("sent");
            String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
            FirebaseUser fu = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            if (fu != null && sent.equals(fu.getUid())) {

                if (!currentUser.equals(user)) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        sendNotification(remoteMessage);


                    } else {
                        sendNormalNotification(remoteMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");


        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        OreoAndAbove oreo = new OreoAndAbove(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreo.getNotifications(title, body, pi, sound, icon);


        int j = 0;
        if (i > 0) {
            j = i;
        }
        oreo.getManager().notify(j, builder.build());


    }

    private void sendNormalNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");


        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

        int i = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int j = 0;
        if (i > 0) {
            j = i;
        }
        nm.notify(j, builder.build());


    }

    private void showPostNotification(String id, String title, String desc) {

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        int nID = new Random().nextInt(3000);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupNotificationChannel(nm);
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_thumb_liked);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "" + id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.search)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(desc)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pi);
        nm.notify(nID, mBuilder.build());


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupNotificationChannel(NotificationManager nm) {

        CharSequence channel = "New Notification";
        String channelDesc = "Device to Device Post Notification";


        NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel("some_id", "Newsy", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        nc.enableLights(true);
        nc.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        nc.enableVibration(false);

        if (nm != null) {
            nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
        }


    }
}
```

**OreoAndAbove.java**

```
public class OreoAndAbove extends ContextWrapper {
    private static final String ID = "some_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Newsy";

    private NotificationManager nm;

    public OreoAndAbove(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel();
        }

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(ID, NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        nc.enableLights(true);
        nc.enableVibration(false);
        nc.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0});
        nc.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(nc);

    }


    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (nm == null) {
            nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return nm;

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Notification.Builder getNotifications(String title, String body, PendingIntent pIntent, Uri sound, String icon) {


        return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), ID)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setChannelId(ID);

    }


}
```

Comment: Did you check the logcat for any exception or errors?

Comment: Yes the logcat is fine